# How do I pass a column name to a model formula in R using dplyr::summarise_at()

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to get some summary statistics from a series of models in R.

For example, I can pass variables to the LHS of a formula:

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(vars(cyl:hp), list(
    r = ~summary(lm(formula = . ~ mpg))$r.squared
  ))

   cyl_r    disp_r      hp_r
1 0.72618 0.7183433 0.6024373
```

But I can't seem to pass variables to the RHS:

```
mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(vars(cyl:hp), list(
    r = ~summary(lm(formula = mpg ~ .))$r.squared
  ))

Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Is there a way to do what I want? I'm vaguely aware I should probably be using purr::map or something but my experiments there have failed.

Thanks in advance.

> ✔ ggplot2 3.2.1     ✔ purrr   0.3.3
>   ✔ tibble  2.1.3     ✔ dplyr   0.8.3
>   ✔ tidyr   1.0.0     ✔ stringr 1.4.0
>   ✔ readr   1.3.1     ✔ forcats 0.4.0

Comment: Is that how summarize_at is working here? I expected it to be passing each variable name individually

Comment: The message is saying that there is no data. So `r = ~summary(lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars))$r.squared` is probably the way to go?

Comment: Thanks, that works and it will save my butt today - but still curious why the first example works but the second example requires the data argument. Is there a way to pass the data argument as a variable so I don't have to update this code every time the name of the dataframe changes?

Comment: @jazzurro Does that give the correct values though? I get the same `r.squared` values for all.

Comment: @RonakShah I am not with my PC now. If you say, you get the same values, what said is not correct.

Comment: I think the same values are expected. The r^2 shouldn't change if the model is inverted... (I think?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not exactly clear how the first one works but using `.x` instead of `.` seem to work.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  summarise_at(vars(cyl:hp), list(
     r = ~summary(lm(formula = mpg ~ .x))$r.squared
  ))

#    cyl_r  disp_r    hp_r
#1 0.72618 0.71834 0.60244
```